# How does one run the Haskell portable install option for GHCi 8.0.1?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

A few years ago a question was asked about installing Haskell without administrator privileges. The answer was to use the portable install option.  But I don't see that option when I download and run the Minimal Installer for GHCi 8.0.1. Is there still a way to do it, and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: What is the "Minimal Installer"? Is this a windows thing?

Comment: The minimal and full installers both have the same problem. They want administrator privileges. See the Haskell platform for windows (https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) for both.

Comment: The Minimal Installer is a minimal release (no extra libraries) of the Haskell Platform. It is available for all platforms.

Comment: Please open an issue in the HP issue tracker: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues

Comment: I got administrator privileges and was able to install and run GHCi.

Comment: I would open an issue in the HP issue tracker if you would tell me where it is and how to get started. Thanks. (Don't forget, this problem arose in the first place because I'm a new user and don't know my way around the Haskell ecology.)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest directly using [Stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) instead?

It's part of what is bundled in the Haskell Platform. But if you just use Stack, there's (for almost all basic use cases) no need anymore for the other things (System-wide installation of GHC and Cabal and a global package database) included there.

The stack executable can [easily be downloaded](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install) and used without admin privileges for most platforms.